# Duplicate reference variable in java

Tags: java

I have a 2 java classes one with main method and one with private variables & methods for getting and setting. So, my question is can we use same object reference variable in all setters(3 setters) and a different reference variable in all getters(3)?
I used that and i got null value.

But, when i use 3 different object reference variable for 3 getters and same respective 3 object reference variable in for getters then it worked ok.
So, can someone explain me this concept?

package project1;

public class Encapsulationjerry1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Now, we are gonna test our Encapsulation");

    // I gave different variables for all setters and same respective variables for getters. This is working fine.
    Encapsulationtom1 obj1 = new Encapsulationtom1();
    Encapsulationtom1 obj2 = new Encapsulationtom1();
    Encapsulationtom1 obj3 = new Encapsulationtom1();

    obj1.setDesignation("Lead Designer");
    obj2.setEmployeeId(23452);
    obj3.setEmployeeName("Meliodas");

    System.out.println("The designation is "+ obj1.getDesignation());
    System.out.println("The Employee Id is "+ obj2.getEmployeeId());
    System.out.println("The Employee Name is "+ obj3.getEmployeeName());

    // But when i give same variable to all setters and a different variable to all getters, it gave me null value.   WHY?
}
```

}

Comment: Lets see some code.

Comment: A good code sample is worth a thousand words...

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/9KEX2aWbKNKD3wcsL4J8HQ

its pasteof.code link :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a null value is because you haven't set the values for those variables for the second case. For example, lets so you do the following:

```
    Encapsulationtom1 obj1 = new Encapsulationtom1();
    Encapsulationtom1 obj2 = new Encapsulationtom1();
    Encapsulationtom1 obj3 = new Encapsulationtom1();

    obj1.setDesignation("Lead Designer");
    obj1.setEmployeeId(23452);
    obj1.setEmployeeName("Meliodas");

    System.out.println("The designation is "+ obj1.getDesignation());
    System.out.println("The designation is "+ obj2.getEmployeeId());
    System.out.println("The designation is "+ obj3.getEmployeeName());
```

These two lines:

```
    System.out.println("The designation is "+ obj2.getEmployeeId());
    System.out.println("The designation is "+ obj3.getEmployeeName());
```

will return `Null` because you haven't given them a value yet. Therefore, the variables for `obj2` and `obj3` will not have been instantiated yet, and calling them will return `null`.

Comment: OK, I think i get it :D
Same object used for setting the value can be used for getting the value :D

Comment: Yup! If you don't set the value in an object, you won't be able to get it and it will just return `null`

Comment: ok, well thank you for your help. I was just not connecting the things for the time being but now it's all perfect :D

Comment: That's great! Don't forget to upvote and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!